# JQuery like selector for selecting tags from a printed DOM tree.

Tags: java, jquery, html, dom

I have the following code which prints the DOM tree of a given html page. I am trying to create a jquery like selector which parse the tree and return tag, id or classes.

```
var myQuery;

$(document).ready(function() {
   function printDomTree(currentNode) { //printing Dom Tree
    //codes for printing DOM Tree
   }

   function traverseDomTree(currentNode, selector) { //traversing Dom tree to get the node value.
     //code for parsing the tree
   }

   myQuery = function(selector) {
     return new MyQuery(selector);
  };

  var MyQuery = function(selector) {
    var nodes = traverseDomTree(currentNode, selector);
    for(var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
      this[i] = nodes[i];
    }      
    this.length = nodes.length;
    return this;
  };
})
```

I have been able to select the tags, id or classes when I use the selector inside the `$(document).ready(function(){ var el = myQuery("div");})`. But I want it to be global and can be able to use in other JS file. I tried using `var el = myQuery("div");` This returns `Uncaught TypeError: myQuery is not a function`
I'm stuck. Can anyone help me out...

Comment: `var MyQuery = function(selector) {`  this should be `MyQuery = function(selector) {` only

Comment: @Katana I have tried that.. still the same. I also tried to move my  `myQuery = function(selector) {
  return new MyQuery(selector);
};` outside `$(document).ready(function(){})` and remover var from `var MyQuery`. It gives `Uncaught ReferenceError: MyQuery is not defined`.

Comment: did you try to change the case? MyQuery to myQuery?

Comment: @Katana I think changing case will create a conflict between function expression `myQuery = function(selector) {
  return new MyQuery(selector);
};` and constructor function `var MyQuery = function(selector) {
      var nodes = getDomElement(domNextSibling, selector);
      for(var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
        this[i] = nodes[i];
      }      
      this.length = nodes.length;
      return this;
    };`